# need to hide picture on Page1 when i will click button on Page2 c#

Tags: c#, wpf

need to hide picture on Page1.xaml when i will click button on Page2 c# wpf
please need example code

i was try this but its not working anything

Page2.xaml.cs

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Page1 p1 = new Page1();
            p1.pic.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Page1.xaml with picture what i need to hide

```
<Image x:Name="gear111" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="114" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114" Source="/gear1.png" Margin="676,461,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: should't it be `p1.pic.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;` ?

Comment: You must set the Visibility on *exactly the same* instance that is already loaded and displayed. Maybe you should read about classes and instances to understand your problem. It's fundamental knowledge. You probably have a class that loads the individual pages. This class already has access to all living pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish it was that simple. In WPF, Pages are isolated from each other. In other words, your `Page2` doesn't know which Controls `Page1` has. You also can't hide a Control on `Page1` from `Page2` this way because whenever you navigate away from `Page1` it's unloaded from memory and any changes you made are lost (unless you save them). In addition, you're most likely navigating to `Page1` by using a `new` instance which resets the page state (i.e., executes the code and loads the image again). You can do it by using `MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)` to monitor both pages and pass data from one to the other, however, I think this approach is futile. But here's how to do it anyway:

- First, create a new `ViewModel` class:

```
class ImageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ImageViewModel(Visibility visibility)
    {
        _imageVisibility = visibility;
    }
    private Visibility _imageVisibility;

    public Visibility ImageVisibility
    {
        get { return _imageVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _imageVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageVisibility");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
}
```

- Second, bind the `Visibility` property of the `Image` to the `Visibility` property you've defined in the `ViewModel` class you just created:

```
<Image x:Name="gear111" ... Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility}"/>
```

- Third, add `DataContext` to `Page1` (where your image is). This passes the data from `ViewModel` class to the `Image` on `Page1`:

```
 public Page1(Visibility visibilty)
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new ImageViewModel(visibilty);
 }
 public Page1()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new ImageViewModel(Visibility.Visible);
 }
```

- Finally, add this code to your `Button_Click` event on `Page2`. When you click the button, this creates a new `Window` instance that shows the changes made to `Page1`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window win = new Window();
    win.Content = new Page1(Visibility.Collapsed);
    win.Show();
}
```

Please note that the page limitations I mentioned above still apply here. You can make the change in `Visibility` persist by saving it to either a bool setting (created in `Settings.settings` in `Properties`) or a local text file that the application can read before loading the page.

I still strongly suggest that you familiarize yourself with `MVVM` (you don't need to fully grasp it as a beginner) and avoid using Windows/Pages when it's unnecessary. Pages are mainly used for navigation purposes or to be viewed through a web browser. For standalone applications, the `MainWindow.xaml` is all you need; you simply add more to it to achieve what you want. Knowing the basics of WPF—`UI Controls`, `Properties`, `Events`, `Classes`, `Data Binding`, [`Project Structure`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18826382/21508272), etc.—will make this a lot easier for yourself.